# sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: CityType: , while compiling: select cityName from CityType

Tags: android

i save the sqlite manager database in assets folder but when i run the program it gives error that"no such table: CityType: , while compiling: select cityName from CityType" but previously it works after uninstalling the program again i run android app. then it gives error "no such table" .....so sir whats the reason???
v v thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to override the onCreate + onUpgrade:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // CREATE TABLE teas (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT NOT
    // NULL, brew_time INTEGER);
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + BREW_TIME + " INTEGER" + ");";
    db.execSQL(sql);
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see
 * android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite
 * .SQLiteDatabase, int, int)
 */
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
```